# Meteor Golem killing planeswalkers

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Meteor Golem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMeteor%20Golem%5d)'s ability is "When Meteor Golem enter the battlefield destroy target nonland permanent".  Does Meteor Golems ability affect planewalkers, which count as players and not really creatures?

Comment: You may be confused by the "planeswalker redirection" rule that allowed the controller of a spell or ability that targeted a player to be redirected to a planeswalker that player controls. This has recently been removed in favor of rewording the spells/abilities themselves to let them target planeswalkers. In any case planeswalkers were always counted as permanents and not players.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, Meteor Golem can target and destroy a planeswalker on the battlefield. The player is a "planeswalker" only in lore terms. As far as game mechanics are concerned, "planeswalker" has a defined meaning, and a planeswalker object is not a player and vice versa.**

A planeswalker in the mechanical sense is a type of object, a game entity that interacts with players and other objects:

> 102.1. A player is one of the people in the game. [..]
>
> 109.1. An object is an ability on the stack, a card, a copy of a card, a token, a spell, a permanent, or an emblem.

A planeswalker is not a creature, as you already noted, but its own permanent type alongside creatures and others:

> 110.4. There are five permanent types: artifact, creature, enchantment, land, and planeswalker.

Therefore, if Meteor Golem can destroy a non-land permanent, then that does include a planeswalker on the battlefield.